# How can I create a tree structure (multi-level list) in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, tree-view

I need to create tree structure in Excel, like a mindmap. As far as I know, it's impossible, so I want to create a multi-level list instead, like in Word:

```
1     |
1.1   |
1.2   |
1.3   |
2     |
2.1   |
2.1.1 |
2.2   |
```

It should be not a simple text, but a real multilevel list: when I insert string after 1.1, it's first cell becomes 1.2, 1.2 and 1.3 becomes 1.3 and 1.4 respectively.

Comment: Do you want this list to automatically update if you insert or delete rows?

Comment: Yes.  And if there is some other way to make a tree structure in Excel, it will be an answer too.